# "Mass communications shapes the world we live in"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, sentence

I am editing a web page and came across this declaration:

```
Mass communications shapes the world we live in
```

It looks wrong to me, but I am wondering if it should be

```
Mass communication shapes the world we live in
```

or

```
Mass communications shape the world we live in
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mass communication shapes the world we live in.

*Mass communication* is being used in an uncountable way here, to refer to a concept, so you use the singular.

Then *shapes* is used to agree with the singular third-person.

Comment: Yes – if one wishes to emphasise the many types of such media, a parenthesis could be inserted: Mass communication, in all its many forms, shapes the world we live in.